# Tkinter 16-bit raw (monochrome) image display w/ scaling?

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a 16-bit image (but only 10-bits effective) in the form of a numpy array. My current code that is used to display the image is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk

from functools import *

import numpy as np

class ImExam():
    def __init__(self):
        self.imExamDisp = Toplevel()

        Label(self.imExamDisp, text="Pixel").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.pixelCoord = Label(self.imExamDisp); self.pixelCoord.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Label(self.imExamDisp, text="Value").grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.pixelValue = Label(self.imExamDisp); self.pixelValue.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.imgDisp = Label(self.imExamDisp, borderwidth=0)
        self.imgDisp.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)

    def updateImage(self, img, dispIMin=None, dispIMax=None):
        self.i = Image.fromarray(img, mode='I;16')
        self.iTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage('I;16', img.shape)
        self.iTk.paste(self.i)

        self.imgDisp.bind('<Motion>', partial(self.getPixelValue, img=self.i))
        self.imgDisp.configure(image=self.iTk)
        self.imgDisp.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)

        self.imExamDisp.update()

    def getPixelValue(self, event, img):
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            value = img.getpixel((x, y))
            self.pixelCoord.configure(text="%02s, %02s" % (x, y))
            self.pixelValue.configure(text="%0.4g" % value)
```

But the resulting image on the screen is 8-bits, despite calling `ImageTk.PhotoImage` in `I;16` mode.

First, this example (namely, `updateImage(img)`) is meant to update a separate Tkinter window with a live image feed, and `getPixelValue` will update the current pixel/value combination. I posted it all in case others could benefit.

But my question is how do I control the display range of the `Label` widget? The resulting 16-bit (10-bit) image is scaled to 8-bits, although the pixel values are correct. My image has the following properties:

```
print np.min(img), np.max(img), img.shape, img.dtype
109 1023 (491, 656) uint16
```

And following that question, can I alter the display scale? e.g. instead of displaying values from 0-1023, can I instead display the image from say 100-800?

Tkinter may not be the way to go for this, so I'm open to other packages. And maybe scaling the image (to between 100-800, e.g.) is better done in numpy or something. That's also acceptable. Any suggestions appreciated!

I can't seem to find a solution to this through PIL docs, other posts, etc...

**EDIT**:

OK, so I'm partly answering my own question; not sure if this is the place to do it, but it might help. I gave `matplotlib` a shot, with the following code instead (interfaced w/ `Tkinter` following the example [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html)):

```
from Tkinter import *

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from functools import *

import numpy as np

class ImExam():
    def __init__(self):
        self.font = ("Helvetica", 9)
        self.imExamDisp = Toplevel()

        Label(self.imExamDisp, text="Pixel").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.pixelCoord = Label(self.imExamDisp); self.pixelCoord.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Label(self.imExamDisp, text="Value").grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.pixelValue = Label(self.imExamDisp); self.pixelValue.grid(row=0, column=3)

        matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.family': "Helvetica", 'font.size': 9})

        #
        ### Setup image window
        #
        self.fig  = Figure(frameon=False)
        self.subPlot = self.fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False);     # add_axes needed to fill image in Figure
        self.subPlot.set_axis_off()

        self.imgDisp = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.imExamDisp)
        self.imgDisp.show(); self.imgDisp.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)

    def updateImage(self, img, dispIMin=0., dispIMax=1023., virtFlag=0):
        self.subPlot.imshow(img, vmin=dispIMin, vmax=dispIMax, interpolation="quadric", aspect='auto', cmap='gray')
        self.imgDisp.draw()

        self.imgDisp.get_tk_widget().bind('<Motion>', partial(self.getPixelValue, img=img))
        self.imgDisp.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)

        self.imExamDisp.update()

    def getPixelValue(self, event, img):
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
        value = img[y, x]     # imshow (or something) switches x, y
        self.pixelCoord.configure(text="%02s, %02s" % (x, y))
        self.pixelValue.configure(text="%0.4g" % value)
```

`img` is still a numpy array with `img.dtype = uint16`. Unfortunately, there is a border of about 6 pixels on the right side and 1 on the bottom of the image that the cursor can't see (goes from 0-489 and 0-649; should be 0-490 and 0-655). I can't tell if this is a frame issue or something else. There is still a pesky black border around the image that I thought `frameon=False` would get rid of, but maybe not...I'll post a comment to this if I figure it out. Please let me know if you've encountered this issue. Thanks!